# Recycler view with auto span count and item width with wrap content

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-gridlayout

I have a `RecyclerView` with a `GridLayoutManger`. I want to use dynamic span count depend on item width.

> I don't want fixed item width.

[image: example]

Comment: You need to use `StaggeredGridLayoutManager`

Comment: @MouaadAbdelghafourAITALI `StaggeredGridLayoutManager` have fixed span count.

Comment: Did my answer helpful to you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use FlexboxLayoutManager from google:

[image]

https://github.com/google/flexbox-layout

Comment: I'm not using image.

Comment: @VijayKumar
If you look accurately, you can see FlexboxLayoutManager which is LayoutManager for recyclerView. That is what you need. Anyway, I've updated my answer.